# Obtener fecha actual en jquery y enviar a formulario html

Tags: php, html, jquery

Necesito que la fecha actual se muestre cuando se carga una página. Lo he intentado usando variable de session o bien, usando una función, pero ninguna me funciona, arrojando error:

Forma 1:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <title>YOYO</title>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            (function(){
                var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
                var f=new Date();
                fecha=(f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
                console.log(fecha);
                ("#fecha").append('<p>fecha</p>')
            }());
        });

    </script>

</head> 

<body>
            <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-end">
                <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha"></span>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>    
            
</body>
</html>
```

Forma 2:

```html
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <title>YOYO</title>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            (function(){
                var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
                var f=new Date();
                fecha=(f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
                console.log(fecha);
                <?php $_SESSION['fecha']=fecha?>
            }());
        });

    </script>

</head> 

<body>

            <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-end">
                <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha"><?php echo $_SESSION['fecha']?></span>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>   
            
</body>
</html>
```

En el segundo caso, me imprime el nombre de la variable "fecha" y no su contenido.

Cuál sería la forma correcta de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera forma funciona correctamente, solo que no esta mostrando los datos correctamente. Pruebalo así.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>YOYO</title>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            (function(){
                var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
                var f=new Date();
                fecha=(f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()] + " de " + f.getFullYear());
                console.log(fecha);
                $("#fecha").append('<p>'+fecha+'</p>')
            }());
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha"></span>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>                
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Una instancia de `Date`

```
let fecha = new Date();
```

Contiene en sí todos los cortes que necesites, y métodos de conveniencia para formatear con la transformación que te acomode. En tu caso, usando [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Si quieres el formato: `<DD> de <nombre mes> de <YYYY>` puedes hacer:

```js
let fecha = new Date(),
  formateada = fecha.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  });

console.log(formateada);
```

O más corto (pero viene con el día de la semana)

```js
let fecha = new Date(),
  formateada = fecha.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {
    dateStyle: 'full'
  });

console.log(formateada);
```

O especificar otra zona horaria (por ejemplo, en Sidney ya es mañana)

```js
let fecha = new Date(),
  formateada = fecha.toLocaleDateString('es-ES', {
    dateStyle: 'full',
    timeZone:'Australia/Sydney'
  });

console.log(formateada);
```

En el código que sale en tu pregunta, que formalmente debiera funcionar, el error está en:

```
  ("#fecha").append('<p>fecha</p>')
```

No estás usando `$("#fecha")`, sino `("#fecha")` que es un String, y no tiene un método `append`. Además imagino que quieres crear un elemento `p` dentro del `span#fecha` con el valor de la fecha y no el string `fecha` de manera que debiera ser:

```
 $("#fecha")  // referencia al <span>, el comando siguiente opera sobre éste
    .append('<p></p>')  // inserto elemento p y éste pasa a ser la referencia
    .text(fecha); // inserto fecha formateada en la referencia a "p"
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function() {
    let fecha = new Date()
      .toLocaleDateString("es-ES", {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric'
      });
    $('#fecha').append('<p></p>').text(fecha);
  }());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>





<div class="row container-fluid mt-1 justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-4 align-self-end">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="fecha"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres obtener la fecha usando javascript, lo podrías usar de esta forma:

```js
let fecha = new Date();
let monthNames = [ "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ]; 
let fechaTexto = `${fecha.getDate()} de ${monthNames[fecha.getMonth()]} de ${fecha.getFullYear()}`;

jQuery('#fecha').val(fechaTexto);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fecha">
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero el motivo de la función es que necesito el nombre del mes y no el número del mes. El formato de fecha debe ser algo como "26 de diciembre de 2019". Por eso tu sugerencia, así tal cual, no me sirve.

Comment: Ok, edite la respuesta para resolver el requerimiento, espero te sirva @JuncoFuerte